# Snowflake aggregate by week

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake table with data as follows date in m/d/y format:

```
Data   User   Transaction Count
1/1/23 User1   5
1/2/23 User1   5
1/3/23 User1   5
1/30/23 User1  10
2/1/23  User1  15
```

and so on. What I am looking to do is calculate sum of `Transaction Count` in the last full week, and compare it to the average of `Transaction Count` in the same week in the prior 4 months. So if I am in week 1 of Feb, I want to consider Week 1 of Jan, Week 1 of Dec, Week 1 of Nov and Week 1 of Oct.
I have managed to aggregate data by week, but am stuck on how to choose the correct weeks in the month prior to calculate the average.

Any thoughts on how to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: if you "I have managed to aggregate data by week", can you share that query so we can work with that?

Comment: Can you share the expected output for the sample data that is being provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try as follows where in get the week of the year and then pick up WHERE WEEK_OF_MONTH = 1

```
 WITH sample_dates AS (
  SELECT dateadd('DAY', SEQ4(), current_date) dt,  
  WEEKOFYEAR(dt) - WEEKOFYEAR(CAST(date_trunc('MONTH',dt) AS DATE))+1 AS  "WEEK_OF_MONTH"
    FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 365)) AS t
)
SELECT * FROM  sample_dates;
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if the date is a string and doesn't get parsed into data first